# How can I test for multivariate equivalence?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, multivariate-analysis, equivalence

I have two sets of data and I want to test to see if they were drawn from the same population/distribution. The data sets have around 200 variables, and I want to be able to take into account the combinations of these 200 variables in determining if they are from the same population. Are there tests out there that will do this?

Also, it's reasonable to assume that these 200 variables are normally distributed on its own, if this makes the problem simpler.